# How to do group by on a different attribute and sum on a different attribute in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin, django-queryset

`models.py`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    total_fees = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    roll_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)

class StudentTransaction(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

`admin.py`:

```
class StudentTransactionModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'time', 'amount']

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'student':
            x = StudentTransaction.objects.order_by().annotate(Sum('amount')).filter(amount__sum__lt=student__total_fees)
            kwargs["queryset"] = [i.student for i in x]
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

While doing `annotate` I want to get all transaction amounts summed up for every student in the function `formfield_for_foreignkey`. I want the actual `Student` objects, so this can't be done using `values`.

To make it simpler, consider that there are 3 `Student` objects. One of them has made 2 transactions, another one has made 4 transactions, and the third one hasn't made any transactions. The sum of transaction amounts per student doesn't exceed the student's `total_fees`. The `formfield_for_foreignkey` should return all `Student` objects those who haven't paid their fees yet. The condition is:

```
sum(<all transactions of each student>) is less than <total_fees of that student>
```

Note: Some details are intentionally removed to keep the code as short as possible. If something is missing or will produce an error, do report it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you need to return `Students` but not `StudentTransaction` you can do that:

```
students = Student.objects.annotate(transactions_sum=Sum('studenttransaction__amount')).filter(transactions_sum__lt=total_fees)
```

If put code to your method it looks like:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'student':
            students = Student.objects.annotate(transactions_sum=Sum('studenttransaction__amount')).filter(transactions_sum__lt=total_fees)
            kwargs["queryset"] = students
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is almost a correct replacement for what I asked. Given the example in the question, it doesn't seem to get students who haven't made any transactions yet. What can be done in such case?

Comment: I got it working using `Student.objects.annotate(transactions_sum=Sum('studenttransaction__amount')).filter(Q(transactions_sum__lt=total_fees) | Q(studenttransaction=None)).distinct()`.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you

`StudentTransaction.objects.annotate(Sum('amount')).values('student').filter(amount__sum__lte=total_fees)`

Comment: Author wants to return `Student` queryset itself, but not `values`. He wrote abote that in description that he doesn't want to use `values()`.